# Was Paul in error for teaching his disciples they were at liberty to eat meat sacrificed to idols and breaking his agreement at the Jerusalem Council?

Tags: contradiction, revelation, acts

Acts 15's Council at Jerusalem was initially to be an inquiry on the subject of circumcision, "certain individuals" who "came down from Judea", one would imagine these were fellow disciples and not unbelieving Jews as their insistence on circumcision lead to a trip to Jerusalem to seek out the wisdom of James/Jacob, who clarifies though the individuals were disciples they were were not under instruction from Jerusalem, and doesn't impose circumcision on the non Jewish disciples.

However, James consults with the Holy Spirit, "28. For it seemed good to the Holy Spirit and to us to impose on you no further burden than these essentials : ...

It also  calls the following Decree "Essential":

Acts 15:29... :that you abstain from what has been sacrificed to idols and from blood and from what is strangled and from fornication. If you keep yourselves from these, you will do well. Farewell. "

Paul and Barnabas part ways at 15:36-41, because Barnabas would not go without John Mark and Paul would not allow him to come, refusing to forgive Mark for deserting him in Pamphylia.

1 Corinthians 8 Now concerning food sacrificed to idols : we know that "all of us possess knowledge." Knowledge puffs up but love builds up. 2. Anyone who claims to know something does not yet have the necessary knowledge ; 3. but anyone who loves God is known by him. ...

Other than the first five words, that paragraph has no relation to eating idol meat specifically, Paul seems to be pitching a higher "gnosis" of sorts.

4. Hence, as to the eating of food offered to idols, we know that "no idol in the world really exists," and that "there is no God but one." 5. Indeed, even though there may be so called gods in Heaven or on earth ----as in fact there are many gods and many lords---- 6. yet for us there is one God, the Father, from whom are all things and for whom we exist, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom are all things and through whom we exist. ...
5. It is not everyone, however, who has this knowledge. Since some have become so accustomed to idols until now, they think of the food they eat as food offered to an idol; and their conscience, being weak, is defiled. 8 "Food will not bring us closer to God."
6. We are no worse off if we do not eat, and no better off if we do. But take care this liberty of yours does not become a stumbling block to the weak.

Paul fails to mention that he is discussing something he previously agreed he would ensure his pupils would adhere to, and teach that eating idol meat was forbidden and this essential.

Instead he grants them the 'liberty' of eating meat sacrificed to idols, because it's harmless and not beneficial, but they were to be cautious of becoming a stumbling block to "the weak."

I think we should be able to agree with Jesus if he clarifies the issue, and he does, in Revelation 2:14:

Message to Pergamum

".... But I have a few things against you : you have some there who hold to the teaching of Balaam, who taught Balak to put a STUMBLING BLOCK  before the people of Israel, so that they would eat food sacrificed to idols and practice fornication."

Like Balaam, Paul taught people to eat meat sacrificed to idols, and is the only person in the New Testament that we can say did this, who says so himself.

Jesus held something against Paul as he did the others whose identity we don't know. We do know factually it was a condemnation of the teaching, by the Messiah himself, so Paul did not receive it from God or Jesus.

I won't speculate where Paul learned this "knowledge" he speaks of that makes sin not sin, which is exactly what he did, I won't speculate why.

I will just ask was Paul wrong and thus guilty of penning uninspired writings?

Is there another option that doesn't require a long explanation for a simple matter of God saying don't ever, Paul saying do sometimes?  A classic case of right and wrong is apparently what we have.

Comment: A short comment: neither Jesus, nor Holy Spirit, nor Father, nor Paul worshiping Them as undivided are sinning. Just, Holy Spirit's instructions for humans are portioned and rationed, thus, in Jerusalem the instruction was "not to eat", yet, the purpose of this was not ontological, but contextual and historical, for ontologically there is nothing wrong in consuming proteins from meat sacrificed to idols, for meat and proteins it consists of do not get tarnished by this. And, if a child was dying of starvation, James also would have given to him any meat. Written word kills Spirit vivifies.

Comment: I am not sure that this question fits the rules of the site because it is not really a question about a particular verse or passage. It appears to be a question about a particular subject - whether it is permissible for mendicant believers to eat the surplus meat that was commonly distributed to the public from Greek pagan sacrifices, and what Paul's view of this question was.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim - I think perhaps the question could have been formatted better, but the OP does seem to be addressing specific texts and whether there is a contradiction between them:  Acts 15:28-29, 1 Corinthians 8:1-9, and Revelation 2:14.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a "contradiction" tag.  I think perhaps the wording of the question could be simplified to reflect that this is a question regarding contradiction between the passages and excise the wording regarding God changing his mind and Jesus, James, the Holy Spirit, or Paul being "wrong".

Comment: @user33515 The four questions at the end of the post are still not hermeneutical questions. They are theological questions, and not very clear questions at that.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim - I completely agree.  Hence my last comment.

Comment: In addition to the above closure reasons, questions should address *a specific* text (maybe two in the case of contradictions), not three or 4, otherwise the question is too broad. For questions about something like this, the Jewish tradition might assert that Paul *was* wrong in teaching this. That also makes answers primarily opinion based (remember, this is [not exclusively](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/996/jewish-hermeneutics-here-too) a [Christian site.](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/friends-we-are-not-christian)

Comment: I tried to save the question from closure by excising a lot of the theological content, but it might not save the patient (or please the author).

Comment: Regarding the notion that it is untrue Paul even gave the liberty of eating meat sacrificed to idols, the only comment I have read so far that is not a sort of complaint about the question itself...

Comment: I disagree. They could not be more clear, and are actually rhetorical, so as to make a point . And if my questions at the end of my post are too confusing for you I will simplify upon request, but I am unclear as to what is not clear and wonder if perhaps criticism is a result of the fact that you can't answer the first question, as the last were  rhetorical and more designed to make a point than solicit an answer, which is something I thought was obvious. And I am not certain how or if Hermeneutics differs from regular exegesis, but my question was based on exegesis and Hermeneutics is a type

Comment: Hermeneutics is defined as the field or branch of knowledge dealing with interpretation, I briefly Googled that definition, and the distinction between theology and interpretation or Hermeneutics is foggy, either way you are interpreting the Bible to draw a conclusion. Biblical interpretation, Hermeneutics, is inherently theological by nature, so a "Theological question", even a rhetorical one, would be pointless if not based on sound interpretation. Hermeneutics is theological exegesis.

Comment: Gazali, this is indeed an interesting and instructive question, but as already pointed out, you've grossly misrepresented Paul's instruction. Paul would also strongly condemn the practices of some of the people in Pergamum and Thyatira in Revelation 2. He expressly directed Christians to NOT put stumbling blocks in the way of weaker Christians.

Comment: I have nnot in any way misrepresented Paul, I quoted entire passages and explained the plain meaning.

Comment: "Take care that this liberty..." to eat or not since he just explained it is harmless because idols don't really exist, which is interesting because God has a Law forbidding meat sacrificed to idols, so I would say they do exist. "Does not become a stumbling block to weak brothers." Clearly meaning do not let it harm them who do not have "this knowledge" that idols do not exist.

Comment: And Paul even admitted to the existence of many gods and many lords, but not for them, using the unambiguous wording "as in FACT there are many gods and many lords" quoted in full above, and since an idol is only limited by whether or not someone worships it, it is an idol, usually representing one of the many gods or lords that in fact do exist. According to Paul. The whole reason for this is that the ancients believed it could cause demon possession if sacrificed to one, as the 4th century MSS Homilies and Recognitions of Clement attributes to Peter this very teaching, which makes sense.

Comment: Now if Paul was in agreement with the message to Palmyra, he would not have said his pupils were at liberty based on some higher knowledge, but he in fact does and called people who adhere to the teaching weak brothers and attributes this to their lack of knowledge of idols. But God is not deficient in knowledge and neither was James, and he is the one who voiced the Decree. God does not tailor His Laws according to individual knowledge but declares His Laws apply to all, first the Hebrews, later to all nations, and the fact is that He Decreed it forbidden while Paul stated it was a liberty.

Comment: I would just like to add that I was accused of asking a question but not seeking the meaning of a Biblical text. But factually speaking asking if Paul was wrong is asking for the meaning of the text which is Biblical. I also contest the notion that it is off topic as well, because it is about the Bible, the topic of the website itself, and it's meaning. I think it is more likely that it is not popular that I mentioned it and the fact that it makes Paul known for teaching it is sometimes acceptable to disagree with God.

Comment: But since nobody will ever be able to factually display that the liberty to eat or not eat was based on the brothers present, and their weakness and lack of knowledge the reason why they were not able to eat it, which is equivalent to calling those obedient to God weak and uneducated... for obeying the Law of God. And that is the knowledge they have that gives them this liberty to eat meat sacrificed to idols, according to Paul, which is the same as saying that if you aquire certain knowledge you can do things forbidden others, who are weak and without knowledge, even saying Jesus is weak.

Comment: I wwill not take offense or get angry. I am familiar with lurking on this website and it seems every issue raised that can't be explained without the explanation being swiftly refuted gets the same treatment. No disrespect intended just a casual observation. Because the reasons given to me for being put on hold are mere opinions and incorrect, and 2 in number that are impossible to always make a question a subject related to as the history of the text is a different subject than it's interpretation unless the history of it is used in interpretation, and the history of the Bible is theoretical.

Answer (score 4):

At the core of your argument are the premises:

> **(A)** The Council of Jerusalem decreed that Gentile converts should abstain from meat offered to idols
>
> **(B)** "Paul taught people to eat meat sacrificed to idols" (your statement verbatim)

Whatever conclusions one draws from these premises, the argument would be unsound.  The second premise is not true.

Paul did not teach people to eat meat sacrificed to idols as you claim.  1 Corinthians 8 is a protracted dialog that actually directs exactly the opposite, if you follow the chapter through to verses 10-11 (you stopped at 9).

The issue that Paul was addressing was that many weak-minded members of the Corinth church were still intentionally eating meat sacrificed to idols, retaining a sort of double-mindedness about their faith.  The more cogent among the community, who knew that this practice was improper were also partaking of these offerings, justifying their actions in the sense that Paul speaks of in v.4ff.  Possibly they were familiar with the Gospel teaching, *not the things which enter in defile the man, but the things which proceed out.*<sup>1</sup>

Rather than immediately and outrightly condemn all parties for the practice, Paul - as he is wont to do - reasons gradually with those addressed, bringing them eventually to his conclusion:

> <sup>1</sup>*Now as touching things offered unto idols, we know that we all have knowledge. Knowledge puffeth up, but charity edifieth.*

This is an offhand slight against those among the Corinthians who, as John Chrysostom described, "made an immoderate use of their perfect knowledge to harm both others and themselves."<sup>2</sup>

> <sup>2</sup>*And if any man think that he knoweth any thing, he knoweth nothing yet as he ought to know.* <sup>3</sup>*But if any man love God, the same is known of him.*

A mild admonition to the "knowledgeable" that they should not be so sure of their knowledge.

> <sup>4</sup>*As concerning therefore the eating of those things that are offered in sacrifice unto idols, we know that an idol is nothing in the world, and that there is none other God but one.* <sup>5</sup>*For though there be that are called gods, whether in heaven or in earth, (as there be gods many, and lords many,)* <sup>6</sup> *But to us there is but one God, the Father, of whom are all things, and we in him; and one Lord Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we by him.*

Here he is not saying directly that he agrees with their conclusion that eating meat offered to idols is correct.  He is merely recapitulating the premises they hold to arrive at their conclusion.

> <sup>7</sup>*Howbeit there is not in every man that knowledge: for some with conscience of the idol unto this hour eat it as a thing offered unto an idol; and their conscience being weak is defiled.* <sup>8</sup>*But meat commendeth us not to God: for neither, if we eat, are we the better; neither, if we eat not, are we the worse.*

Here he is now touching on how those who are "knowledgeable" are harming their weaker brethren with false doctrine.

> <sup>8</sup>*But take heed lest by any means this liberty of yours become a stumblingblock to them that are weak.*

Now he is beginning his chastisement in earnest, mild at first, then stern:

> <sup>10</sup>*For if any man see thee which hast knowledge sit at meat in the idol’s temple, shall not the conscience of him which is weak be emboldened to eat those things which are offered to idols;*
> <sup>11</sup>*And **through thy knowledge shall the weak brother perish**, for whom Christ died?* <sup>12</sup>*But when ye sin so against the brethren, and wound their weak conscience, ye sin against Christ.*

He even goes so far as to direct the Corinthians that they should not just avoid meat offered to idols, but - if the case should arise - any kind of meat at all, if it causes a brother somehow to stumble:

> <sup>13</sup> *Wherefore, if meat make my brother to offend, I will eat no flesh while the world standeth, lest I make my brother to offend.*

This is a good example where considering only a part of a passage out of context can lead to a radically different interpretation.  A very thorough and complete exegesis of the Corinthians passage can be found in John Chrysostom's homilies, among others.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>Matthew 15:11</sup>
<sup>2.</sup> <sup>[*Homily XX on First Corinthians*](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf112.iv.xxi.html) (tr. from the Greek)</sup>
<sup>3.</sup> <sup>*Ibid.*</sup>

Comment: Well considered.

Comment: Great answer—Paul doesn't tell anyone to "eat meat sacrificed to idols".

Comment: I am afraid that is incorrect, that I provided the quote which proves it and that simply denying the fact will not answer the question regarding was it wrong or not, which is the question, not did he, because he he absolutely declared his pupils, due to their knowledge apparently, that they were at liberty to eat so long as it did not BECOME a stumbling block, suggesting it is not a stumbling block unless weak brothers are effected by it. The wording is clear and my exegesis sound. "But take care thato this liberty of yours does not become a stumbling block to the weak."

Comment: As if they didn't have the liberty there would be no need for the warning not to let this liberty effect the weak brothers, and worse is that he calls those who obey the Decree of God "weak."

Comment: You said "Here he is now touching on how those who are "knowledgeable" are harming their weaker brethren with false doctrine.  That is not in the text. You inferred it as though the "knowledgeable were teaching false doctrine.